# AngularJS console.log returns true data then empty object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a factory:

```
app.factory("ExampleFactory", function() {
    return {
        map: {}
    }
});
```

And controller:

```
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope, $http, ExampleFactory) {
    $scope.map = ExampleFactory.map;

    $scope.init = function() {
        $http.get("/api") //success
            .success(function(result) {
                $scope.map = exampleMethod(result);
                console.log($scope.map); //{ "1": Object, "2": Object }
            });
        console.log($scope.map); //Object {}
    };

    $scope.init();
});
```

Why in the first case it returns an array but then returns nothing?

UPDATE: Sorry, there was another problem and it was solved by me. I will not delete the answer because I received a correct solutions for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first case that returns an array is actually executed second. The program flow is as follows:

1. `$scope.map` is set to an empty object by the factory.
2. `$scope.init` is called
3. `$http.get` sends an http  request to "/api" (but the request is not returned yet)
4. `$scope.map` is printed to `console.log`, still an empty object
5. At some point after this, the web server returns your http request, at which point the `.success` function is called.
6. `exampleMethod` sets `$scope.map` to an array
7. `$scope.map` is printed to `console.log`, at which point it is an array

Comment: That's true! The first log that I see in browser is an empty object. But how can I implement what I want?

Comment: If you provide more info in your question about what you're wanting, I can look to see how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be retuning empty first in the console and then the array.

This is because the callback that you are passing to the success method is executed asynchronously when the response from the `GET /api` is received. Let's explain it inside your code:

```
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope, $http, ExampleFactory) {
    $scope.map = ExampleFactory.map;

    $scope.init = function() {
        // Get request to the /api
        $http.get("/api") //success
            // here we instruct it to use our function if success 
            // but it is not executed until the response is received.
            .success(
                // Callback that is executed on success HTTP 200
                function(result) {
                     $scope.map = exampleMethod(result);

                     // Second console.log displayed after receiving 
                     // the response to the $http.get call
                     console.log($scope.map); //{ "1": Object, "2": Object }
                }
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////
                );

        // First console.log will display empty object
        console.log($scope.map); //Object {}
    };

    $scope.init();
});
```

Does this makes sense to you?

Happy coding!